# MySQL SQL Query 0 or 1

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple question. I have an SQL query that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    [...]
    `ABC` BIT()
    [...]
)
```

I want `ABC` to be either `0` or `1`I am just wondering, is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bit` has some [oddities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-values.html) that go along with it in new version of MySQL.  I'd suggest using a `bool` or `tinyint(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the `()`:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    [...]
    `ABC` BIT, 
    [...]
)
```

Like most people, I usually pick `TINYINT(1)` over `BIT`, but I think this is fine.

The issue with MySQL is that it doesn't have a real Boolean data type, and neither `TINYINT` nor `BIT` can represent a column that holds exactly two non-`NULL` values of `0` and `1` (they have different ranges of values). The only way is to emulate it with a really small numeric column and pray nobody sneaks in non-zero-or-one values...

Comment: This is really hard to give the answer "check" to. You answered my question on how to use `BIT` but according to @Donnie it would be better to use a boolean or tinyinteger.

Comment: @ahonorstudent: Exactly. I suggest you go with `TINYINT` as well. `BOOL` is another name for `TINYINT(1)`.

Comment: Who should I gave the "check" to?

Comment: @ahonorstudent: It depends on whose advice you choose to follow. Or you could give it to Donnie since he answered first :)